# Getting Data of Specific year from database to show in gridview - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview

I have a gridview in MVC project which display all records from a table but I want to display just current year's records and on clicking backward or forward arrow the records changes to the previous or next year accordingly.
I just have a `ActionResult Index` to which returns a list how do I implement a query here?
here is the code in my contrller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.tbl_HolidayList.ToList());
        }
```

and here is my view code

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
           @* <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Id)
                </div>
            </td>*@
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Name, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Name)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Description, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_Description)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_date, new { style = "display: none; width:170px; height:15px" })
                <div class="displaytext">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Holiday_date)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Holiday_Id }, new { @class = "lnkEdit" }) |
               @* @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Holiday_Id}, new { @class = "lnkDetail" }) |*@
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Holiday_Id![enter image description here][1] }, new { @class = "lnkDelete" })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the index method return values for the current year and a separate method that returns values for a specific year as a partial view

Controller (assume HolidaysController)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
public ActionResult Details(int year)
{
  var model = db.tbl_HolidayList.Where(h => h.Holiday_date.Year == year);
  return PartialView(model);
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
  int year = DateTime.Today.Year;
}

<button type="button" id="previous">Previous</button>
<div id="year">@year</div>
<button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
<div id="details">
  @Html.Action("Details", "Holidays", new { id = year })
</div>

<script>
  var year = '@year';
  var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Holidays")'; // Assumes the controller is HolidayController
  var updateHolidays = function() {
    $('#year').text(year);
    $('#details').load(url, { id: year });
  } 
  $('#previous').click(function() {
    year--;
    updateHolidays();
  }
  $('#next').click(function() {
    year++;
    updateHolidays;
  }
```

Details.cshtml (partial)

```
@model IEnumerable<tbl_HolidayList>
<table>
  ....
  <thead>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Holiday_Id, new { @class = "control", id = "" })
          ....
        </td>
        ....
      </tr>
    }
  </thead>
</table>
```

css

```
.control { // could be just input[type="text"] {
  display:none;
  height:15px;
  width: 100%; // style the column widths!
}
```

Note: use a class name for styling the textboxes (not inline styles) and use `id = ""` to remove the `id` attribute from the textbox (otherwise your creating duplicate `id`'s which is invalid html)

Answer (score 0):

I would :

- Update your Controller to take an (int year) parameter and only return the appropriate data (no need to retrieve everything)
- Create a partial view with your table in it
- When clicking on Previous/Next, I would do a jQuery ajax request to retrieve the data (return a PartialViewResult for example)

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario we do not know how many rows will be there for a year. So better to handle "previous" and "next" button click event and fire a AJAX call which calls an Action method to get data and then refresh the content of WebGrid.

While making AJAX call read current year value and add +1 or -1 based on which button is clicked. Then send it to an Action method as parameter (Action method will be a POST type)...Now Action method will filter data for given year and return it to view. Hope following articles may help to implement this scenario:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210927202530/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121510-1.aspx

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/59b91531-3fb2-4504-84a4-9f52e2d65c20.aspx

Thanks.

Comment: I have a a gridview not a webGrid.